# Application functionality calls for saving Credit Card details for future ease. Need to investigate if any specific security design exists for this

Tags: android, security, validation, credit-card

Hi i Need to know if any specific security design exists for saving credit card details of user for future use.Actually iam developing an application in android and its like an app market selling products and i want to implement this functionality ie payment through credit card.

Answer (score 4):

DO NOT save user credit card data on a device!   There's just no way to make it secure.  A device can get lost or stolen.   You'll have to implement a secure user login to your server and store the CC data there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to charge a user's credit card at future dates you would use a service like [Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager (CIM)][3] to create payment profiles for your customers. Basically you're storing credit card information on Authorize.Net's servers and whenever you want to receive a payment from a customer you tell Authorize.Net to charge the amount due to that payment profile.

They even just released [SDKs for Andorid and iOS](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/).